# Taking picture with camera is not working Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to build an app based on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) tutorial, but for some reason my app is crashing. I've searched and tried a lot of ideas but still have not progressed.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I use these permissions and provider looks like this.

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And also have file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/example.com.camera/files/Pictures" /
</paths>
```

I also created imageview and capture button same as it is in tutorial.
I tried to debug it and found out that error happens in this function, and code is stuck on if statement and not passing it. I found something that helped pass if(changing if to this helped getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) but then again app kept crashing on FileProvider.getUriForFile()...

```
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is just copy-paste of that tutorial and I only created View and buttons.
So please have any of you experienced something like that before? I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying it on Android 10 or 11 where scope storage is enabled. Try to save your captured photo on internal storage, so change

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" 
 path="Android/data/example.com.camera/files/Pictures" /
```

with

```
 <files-path   name="."  path="/" />
```

and save your file on getFiles() directory not in external storage. If you want also see your captured photos in gallery you can take a copy from filesDir() to external storage by InputStream() and OutputStream()

Comment: I'm using emulator with android 11, but that(and queries in manifest) worked, rly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer from Ahmet(I'm really thankfull) and adding this queries in manifest worked!

```
 <queries>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>

    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```